# Simulink: find Constellation Diagram Block from Constellation Diagram Plot

Tags: simulink, constellation

I am modifying a very large simulink model for a DSP system.  I am currently looking at a constellation diagram plot that has a problem.  Is there a simple way I can find the Constellation Diagram Block in the simulation model which is producing that Constellation Diagram Plot?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Constellation Plot

Right-click in anything in the very top line of the diagram

Choose to "show toolstrip"

Once toolstrip is showing, look
PLOT > SIGNAL > HIGHLIGHT BLOCK

Click on HIGHLIGHT BLOCK and the block you want will be opened in the simulink model window.